# UICollectionView not updating properly in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

In my app I have a very specific use `UICollectionView` (`CV` for short) with 4 or less cells.

The `CV` is set to fill the screen between two controls (top control anchored to parent view's top, bottom control anchored to parent view's bottom). I'm using an `ObservableCollection` for holding the items, in my ViewModel, and a custom `MvxCollectionViewSource` (`CVS` for short) that does the following:

- Defines two cell types
- Defines a custom `CollectionViewLayout` (I'm using dynamic size cells based on the size of the screen, a single cell can take up 1/2 of the screen minus 8.0 padding on both sides and a 64.0 padding in the center, reserved for an icon)
- Passes the index of the item (`indexPath.Row`) to the item (for future display)
- Passes a command from the ViewModel to the cell (the cells have a "delete" button that are bound to this command)
- Overrides `GetItemsCount` so we always return +1 (an add button) if the actual item count is below the set limit (which is 4 right now)

The ViewModel also has a command for `SelectionChanged` of the `CVS`, all it does is navigate to a new ViewModel that allows editing of the selected items' properties.

My main issue is that until all four items are present, the items seemingly fail to update (a value representing the total count of sub-items within the main item). I've tried calling `ReloadData` on the `CV`, to no avail. But if I have all four items, the update works just fine.

The code is the following:

```cs
public partial class MyView : MvxViewController<MyViewModel> {

    protected MyCollectionSource CollectionViewSource { get; set; }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        this.CollectionViewSource = new MyCollectionSource(this.CollectionView);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();

        set.Bind(this.CollectionViewSource).To(vm => vm.Items);
        set.Bind(this.CollectionViewSource).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To(vm => vm.ShowDetailCommand);

        set.Apply();

        CollectionViewSource.RemoveCommand = ViewModel.RemoveCommand;
        this.CollectionView.Source = CollectionViewSource;
        this.CollectionView.AllowsSelection = true;
        this.CollectionView.ApplySelectionWorkAround();
        this.CollectionView.ReloadData();
    }
}

public class MyCollectionSource : MvxCollectionViewSource
{
    public IMvxCommand<Item> RemoveCommand { get; set; }

    public MyCollectionSource(UICollectionView collectionView) : base(collectionView)
    {
        collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(ItemCell.Nib, ItemCell.Key);
        collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(AddItemCell.Nib, AddItemCell.Key);
        collectionView.CollectionViewLayout = new ItemViewLayout();
    }

    protected override UICollectionViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        return (UICollectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(GetCellKey(indexPath), indexPath);
    }

    protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Item == ItemsSource.Count()) return null;
        var item = base.GetItemAt(indexPath);
        if (item is Item realItem)
        {
            realItem.RemoveCommand = (IMvxCommand)this.RemoveCommand;
            realItem.Index = indexPath.Row + 1;
        }

        return item;
    }

    private NSString GetCellKey(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Item == ItemsSource.Count()) return AddItemCell.Key;

        return ItemCell.Key;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return ItemsSource.Count() < MaximumItems ? ItemsSource.Count() + 1 : ItemsSource.Count();
    }
}

public class ItemViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    public override CGSize ItemSize
    {
        get
        {
            return new CGSize(((UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 2 * 8f) - 64f) / 2, 88f);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried reloading the items on `ViewWillAppear`, on `OnViewModelPropertyChanged` (if the property name is the `ObservableCollection` used to hold the items), tried putting RaisePropertyChanged calls everywhere where navigation back to MyView happens, to no avail. But again - if the `ItemsSource.Count()` is the maximum, it works just fine, but if it is less, it does not.

I'm using MvvmCross 5.1.1, with the new navigation pattern, passing the selected item as parameter to the detail view.

How could I force the CollectionView to display up-to-date data?

Comment: You're not seeing any errors from the UICollectionView, like 'assertion failure' or NSInternalInconsistencyException?

Comment: No, nothing like that. I can see even the PropertyChanged event raised, but even though the CollectionViewSource is bound, nothing happens.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?